Странные иероглифы при миграции таблиц из postgresql в django
Имеется база данных postgreSQL. Кодировка сервера и клиента UTF8. При выполнении python manage.py inspectdb > example/models.py
Вместо символов на кириллице в названия таблиц и полей в models.py выходит что-то похожее на 'id_шёїюф ∙хую'.
Использую psycopg.
Пробовал set PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8
В settings.py добавил 'OPTIONS': { 'client_encoding': 'UTF8', }
Менял этот параметр на 'OPTIONS': { 'options': '-c client_encoding=utf8', }
Добавил в settings.py DEFAULT_CHARSET = 'utf-8
Есть ли возможность избавиться от этой проблемы или нужно будет заново пилить БД, процедуры, представления?
